# editing the course settings form

Tags: php, moodle

I am editing the course settings form in moodle and it works, he added the field but not saved, if I change the database saved data are printed on the input. just not saved ...

**edit_form.php:**

```
    $mform->addElement('text', 'hora', 'Hora do Curso', 'maxlength="100" size="20"');
    $mform->setType('hora', PARAM_TEXT);
    if (!empty($course->id)) {
        $mform->setConstant('hora', $course->hora);
    }

    $mform->addElement('text', 'local', 'Local do Curso', 'maxlength="100" size="20"');
    $mform->setType('local', PARAM_TEXT);
    if (!empty($course->id)) {
        $mform->setConstant('local', $course->local);
    }
```

I need to edit other files?